# Product review doesn't show woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi i enabled the review on woocommerce and doesn't show on products page and i put this code in snippets

```
function bbloomer_product_reviews_shortcode( $atts ) {

if ( empty( $atts ) ) return '';

if ( ! isset( $atts['id'] ) ) return '';
   
$comments = get_comments( 'post_id=' . $atts['id'] );

if ( ! $comments ) return '';

$html .= '<div class="woocommerce-tabs"><div id="reviews"><ol class="commentlist">';

foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {   
  $rating = intval( get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rating', true ) );
  $html .= '<li class="review">';
  $html .= get_avatar( $comment, '60' );
  $html .= '<div class="comment-text">';
  if ( $rating ) $html .= wc_get_rating_html( $rating );
  $html .= '<p class="meta"><strong class="woocommerce-review__author">';
  $html .= get_comment_author( $comment );
  $html .= '</strong></p>';
  $html .= '<div class="description">';
  $html .= $comment->comment_content;
  $html .= '</div></div>';
  $html .= '</li>';
}

$html .= '</ol></div></div>';

return $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'bbloomer_product_reviews_shortcode' );
```

I checked the enable review to the all products and in woocommerce to and in the discussions

Comment: where did you put this `woocommerce_after_single_product` shortcode?

Comment: In functions.php

Comment: where did you put `[woocommerce_after_single_product]`?

Comment: This is the shortcode i used it [product_reviews id="id for product"] not [woocommerce_after_single_product]. I put it in product description

Comment: you should put this `[woocommerce_after_single_product]` rather than `[product_reviews ]` shortcode

Comment: I put it but doesn't work its just appear the text

Comment: where exactly you want to display can you give a screenshot?

Comment: In every product-page, this is 1 product https://ibb.co/Ptt5p10

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new tab using the action hook `woocommerce_product_tabs`. check the below code. code goes in your active theme functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_custom_product_tabs' );
function woo_custom_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    $tabs['products_review_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Reviews', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 120,
        'callback'  => 'products_review_tab_content'
    );

    return $tabs;

}
```

Now you can `echo do_shortcode[]` inside `products_review_tab_content` callback.

```
function products_review_tab_content() {
    global $product;
    echo do_shortcode( '[product_reviews_shortcode id="'.$product->id.'"]' );
}

function product_reviews_shortcode( $atts ) {
    
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => ''
    ), $atts, 'product_reviews_shortcode' );

    $comments = get_comments( array(
        'post_id' => $atts['id'] 
    ) );

    if ( ! $comments ) return '';

    $html .= '<div class="woocommerce-tabs"><div id="reviews"><ol class="commentlist">';

    foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {   
      $rating = intval( get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rating', true ) );
      $html .= '<li class="review">';
      $html .= get_avatar( $comment, '60' );
      $html .= '<div class="comment-text">';
      if ( $rating ) $html .= wc_get_rating_html( $rating );
      $html .= '<p class="meta"><strong class="woocommerce-review__author">';
      $html .= get_comment_author( $comment );
      $html .= '</strong></p>';
      $html .= '<div class="description">';
      $html .= $comment->comment_content;
      $html .= '</div></div>';
      $html .= '</li>';
    }

    $html .= '</ol></div></div>';

    return $html;

}
add_shortcode( 'product_reviews_shortcode', 'product_reviews_shortcode' );
```

**Tested and works.**

[image]

Comment: Can you help where i need to put the codes in functions.php?

Comment: You can add it anywhere in the functions.php file.

Comment: I used that comments_template() and its appeared in functions.php